# Nelmio CorsBundle only applies to OPTIONS | Symfony

Tags: symfony, request, cors, nelmiocorsbundle

Okay so, I have this symfony project which uses two different ports,

[CLIENT] http://localhost:8080 and [SERVER] 127.0.0.1:3000.

So obivously I was getting the CORS error, after doing some research I've found Nelio CorsBundle for Symfony. However, the options I specify are only applied to the OPTIONS/preflight request, the GET or POST remain without any headers from this bundle. This is my setup:

```
  nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin-regex: true
        allow_origin:   ["^http://localhost:[0-9]+"]
        allow_methods:  ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_headers:  ["Content-Type", "authorization", "x-api-token", "cache-control", "x-requested-with"]
        expose_headers: ["link"]
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

And the OPTIONS request it does before hand is fine, with all the given settings applied, however the request following it shows the following error in the console: 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

And when taking a look at the request, there are indeed, no headers present. Does anybody know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your client running on 127.0.0.1? I don't think this matches your "localhost" regex.

Comment: In this case it doesn’t but i’ve done it with ‘^127.0.0.1:[0-9]’ too and also with regex disabled + using *, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I'm an idiot; these requests still got into their respective actions, which I found peculiar. But, since the parameters that I sent with it weren't in the Request, but they were in my request parameters I assumed that was due to the origin headers missing.

Why were those headers missing? I had a die; in my controller, and I did not know that removed the headers. The reason why my parameters were missing was for an entirely different reason.

So, an oversight by me.